# What is the minimum number of bits I need to express a n-bit, signed std_logic_vector in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I'm new to VHDL and am trying to find a way to take a n bit (stored as a generic) signed number and truncate it to a form that requires the minimum number of bits.

For example, if I have 5 as its 8 bit signed number (stored in a std_logic_vector of length 8) 00000101, I'd like to make a function to return 0101 as a std_logic_vector. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have specified that you're using a signed value, you may want to use the `signed` type (from the numeric_std library) instead of the more generic `std_logic_vector`.

If your number is a compile time constant, you can write a function starting from the leftmost bit (in a for loop for example) that counts how many identical bits it sees, then returns `signed_input(8-result downto 0)`. The issue with this is that as a compile time constant, there isn't much advantage in removing the redundant bits. The whole vector will be optimized away in synthesis.

You might want to include special cases to make the result at least 1 bit (0 technically doesn't need any bits to represest) or 2 bits (-1 only needs the sign bit to distinguish it from 0) depending on how you want to use your `signed` type value.

If your number is a real signal (the value changes during operation), you can still count the number of identical bits from the left, but variable location slicing of the vector will be iffy. Are you trying to pack the most of several numbers into a fixed bit width? Doing that will synthesize into multiplexers for each bit as well as the LUTs used for calculating the number of redundant bits for each of the numbers.

Comment: I'm trying to implement Booth's Multiplication Algorithm. For this, I need to assign one of the port inputs (specifically the one input that requires the least number of bits to express its numerical input)  to the signal r.

Comment: @chitown21 so are you trying to determine which of two inputs takes the fewest bits to represent, or are you actually trying to truncate it going into your algorithm? Bear in mind that if your multiplier is capable of handing an `n`x`m` bit multiplication, that it can't be any smaller in hardware for smaller inputs. You may be able to reduce the clock cycles that it takes to run though.

Comment: To be more specific I need to first find which of the two inputs takes the fewest bits to represent. I then need to truncate the resultant of this first operation for use in the remainder of the algorithm. I understand that it will reduce the number of clock cycles for the algorithm to run, however I'm trying to optimize the code for resource utilization. Do you mind explaining how it won't be any smaller in hardware for smaller inputs?

Comment: If your multiplier can support any inputs `a` and `b` of size `n` and `m`, then the hardware to multiply the largest values of `a` and `b` has to exist. It can't go away when `a` and `b` have smaller values. If your control unit is clever (and your process is sequential, not pipelined) then it can stop the algorithm early with smaller inputs. If the hardware was smaller (fewer resources) then your multiplier wouldn't work when you tried to use larger input values.

Comment: Note that you **can** add compile time constants limiting `n` and `m` for your inputs, which will reduce resource utilization, but it limits the functionality of the synthesized multiplier. In most cases, you still wouldn't need to truncate the values because the upper bits that remain constant would be optimized away.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So my ideas, as outlined above,  simply adjust the control unit and would stop the algorithm early for smaller inputs (thus reducing the number of clock cycles). However, this adjustment would still utilize the same number of resources (if not more since it would require more comparisons and logic to determine the least number of bits and then truncate), correct?

Comment: Exactly. The clock cycle reduction is a latency improvement, which also slightly improves throuput (calculations per unit of time). If you want maximum throughput then you need a fixed latency for pipelining (worse on utilization though, needs logic for each stage to exist at all times instead of reusing the logic each cycle), so even the early stop for smaller inputs wouldn't help there. I think you're already using the minimum resources for this type of problem (using a single add/subtract unit each cycle for a multi-cycle calculation).

Comment: Also bear in mind that if you're actually trying to do multiplication for something else (i.e. not a project to show that you can implement booths multiplication) then most FPGA's have dedicated multiplication hardware in them in the form of DSP slices that can do this faster and more area efficiently.

Comment: Is there a way I can check the resource utilization for this innate multiplication hardware? I'm using XILINX

Comment: It depends on your specific FPGA. The ones that contain DPSs can do at least an 18x18 multiplication with a single DSP slice. I have heard (but not personally tested) that doing a simple `a*b` with `signed` type signals will infer a DSP multiplier (make sure you have both sides registered). You can check this after place and route (and maybe after synthesis) by verifying that the utilization reports in ISE or Vivado show used DSP slices.

Comment: @chitown21 I confirm a*b results in a multiplier on Xilinx and Altera. On Xilinx, you should put registers before and after (on `a`, `b` and `m`) to get good timings. These registers can't have asynchronous reset, since it's not supported by the embedded multiplier. On Xilinx, the DSP block also includes a pre-adder and post-adder/accumulator. You can also use * without embbedded mutliplier. You loose control over the algorithm and the result will be a full 1-cycle multiplier, but it's fine for small sizes. In the report, look for DSP/DSP48 utilization, it appears on the top utilization report